# How to remove caption of field in DevExpress ASPxGridView EditForm

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, custom-controls, aspxgridview

I am developing a custom column for DevExpress ASPxGridView.

At EditForm, I replaced the default edit textbox with a custom control that contains some other controls (label-textbox pairs).

Everything is working properly except one thing: since I have my own labels, I want to remove the edit form caption and expand my custom control to be rendered smoothly within the flow of other controls in the EditForm.

The EditForm is rendered as nested tables, then I am able to solve my problem manually in Chrome, by hiding the `<td>` that contains the caption, and expanding the `colspan` of the the `<td>` that contains my custom control, but I want to do this programmatically, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide column caption in the edit form, set the [GridViewDataColumn.EditFormSettings.CaptionLocation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridColumnEditFormSettings_CaptionLocationtopic) property to ASPxColumnCaptionLocation.None